# How set a while with a function

Tags: functions, loop, code

i have a simple function and i need that while it execute my function it set a variable to true, otherwise false. the execution would be my condition.

```
while run this func 

function need() {                                           
        $updates = get_point();
        echo  $updates['selector']; 
        echo 'done';
        }
```

i need that my $set is true, otherwise false. how can i put the func inside?

Comment: This sounds like a pure PHP question, it would be better on stack overflow. What are you trying to do that requires this? What the problem this solves

Comment: This question lacks of explanation. $set even exist in your code. Could explain better?

Comment: i have the define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', $test); and i want change while my function run

Comment: you can't undefine something once it's been defined

Comment: Your code is still unclear, but if for some reason you want to apply / not apply the `DISALLOW_FILE_MODS` directive you sholud not define it as constant ( once defined cannot be undefined as per @TomJNowell comment above) but try to use instead the correspondent filter 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/file_mod_allowed/

Comment: the need function mainly takes the updates to be done using wp_get_update_data (), I changed it a bit for something I did before. however this function does not work with DISALLOW_FILE_MODS, but I need both. your proposal may work, i'm trying to use it but i'm probably doing something wrong. I need to disable the disallow when I use the function and then "reactivate"

Answer (score 0):

a. from the ***return***

```
function dosome(){ return true; }
OR
function dosome( param = true ){ return param; }

var = dosome();
while ( var ){ need(); }
```

b. while loop from fixed param TRUE

```
function need( $param = true) {

  while ( param ){
    $updates = get_point();
    echo  $updates['selector']; 
    echo 'done';
  }                                           

}
need();
```

c. while loop from fixed param FALSE

```
function need( $param = false) {

  while ( param ){
    $updates = get_point();
    echo  $updates['selector']; 
    echo 'done';
  }                                           

}
var = true;
need( var );
```